# Stick a CGPath to the bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, algorithm, cocoa-touch

I have a `CGPath` that I re-draw and everything works great, the problem is that the view sticks to the top instead of to the bottom, I'm sure the solution is really simple but I just can't find what should I change.

here is my code, I'll really appreciate if you'll take a look. Thanks!

```
let boundingBox = CGPathGetBoundingBox(myPath)

let boundingBoxAspectRatio = CGRectGetWidth(boundingBox)/CGRectGetHeight(boundingBox)
let viewAspectRatio = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)/CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)

var scaleFactor = 1.0 as CGFloat
if (boundingBoxAspectRatio > viewAspectRatio) {
    // Width is limiting factor
    scaleFactor = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)/CGRectGetWidth(boundingBox)
} else {
    // Height is limiting factor
    scaleFactor = CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)/CGRectGetHeight(boundingBox)
}


// Scaling the path ...
var scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
// Scale down the path first
scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(scaleTransform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
// Then translate the path to the upper left corner
scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(scaleTransform, -CGRectGetMinX(boundingBox), -CGRectGetMinY(boundingBox))

let scaledSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(boundingBox.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor))
let centerOffset = CGSizeMake((CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)-scaledSize.width)/(scaleFactor*2.0),
                                 (CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)-scaledSize.height)/(scaleFactor*2.0))
scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(scaleTransform, centerOffset.width, centerOffset.height);

let transformedPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &scaleTransform)
```